# Error waiting for SSH: Packer experienced an authentication error when trying to connect via SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, packer

I am trying to build an AWS AMI with packer. here is my packer conf:

```
source "amazon-ebs" "base-alpine" {

  assume_role {
    role_arn     = "arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account_id}:role/admin-ci"
    session_name = "packer"
  }

  source_ami_filter {
    filters = {
      virtualization-type = "hvm"
      name                = "alpine-3.15.0*"
      root-device-type    = "ebs"
    }
    owners      = ["538276064493"]
    most_recent = true
  }

  subnet_filter {
    filters = {
      "tag:Function" : "public"
      "tag:Project" : "brain"
    }
    most_free = true
  }

  security_group_filter {
    filters = {
      "tag:Function" : "public"
      "tag:Project" : "brain"
    }
  }

  ami_name                    = "base-alpine"
  instance_type               = "t4g.medium"
  region                      = "${var.aws_region}"
  ssh_username                = "alpine"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  force_deregister            = true
  force_delete_snapshot       = true

  tags = {
    Project  = "brain"
    Name     = "base-alpine"
  }

}

build {
  sources = ["source.amazon-ebs.base-alpine"]

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "hostname.sh"
    destination = "/tmp/hostname.sh"
  }

  provisioner "shell" {
    valid_exit_codes = [0, 1]
    inline = [
      "doas apk -U upgrade"
    ]

  }

}
```

I was using exactly the same config before but with different base AMI and it was working just fine.

now after I'v changed the base AMI I am receiving this error:

```
==> amazon-ebs.base-alpine: Error waiting for SSH: Packer experienced an authentication error when trying to connect via SSH. This can happen if your username/password are wrong. You may want to double-check your credentials as part of your debugging process. original error: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
```

The interesting part is that I can ssh into the created Packer machine with the generated ssh private key without any problems.

Any ideas why is this happening? or maybe suggestions for a better debug?

Comment: What was the AMI where this was working?

Comment: ubuntu `name = "ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"` `owners      = ["099720109477"]`

Comment: Checking the documentation, it seems that older Alpine AMI had a user `alpine` provisioned for initial SSH. However, it seems that newer versions no longer have an initial user setup for SSH. Ubuntu definitely always has the `ubuntu` user setup initially for SSH.

Comment: why I am able then to do the `ssh -i ~/packer_generated_key alpine@xx.xx.xx` on the same EC2 that packer is failing to do?

Comment: You should probably execute the build with verbose logging enabled and see the command Packer is executing.

Comment: The openssh config that ships with the AWS alpine 3.15 cloud image does not appear to support RSA keys by default.  I see the following error logged in /var/log/messages as the packer client tries to connect via ssh: "userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms".  Downgrading to the alpine 3.14 cloud image worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

What I found out is that my version of packer didn't support key pairs type ED25519 by default and required a specific parameter to work.

```
  region                  = "eu-west-2"
  ssh_username            = "ubuntu"
  temporary_key_pair_type = "ed25519"
```

more info here
https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/packer-unable-to-ssh-into-amazon-linux-2022/33519/2

Answer (score 2):

I'll put the comment from @Beevik here

> The openssh config that ships with the AWS alpine 3.15 cloud image does not appear to support RSA keys by default. I see the following error logged in /var/log/messages as the packer client tries to connect via ssh: "userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms". Downgrading to the alpine 3.14 cloud image worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This failure occurs when in source a wrong ssh_username is used:

source "amazon-ebs" "somename" {
...
**ssh_username** = "here a wrong name"
}
for amazon linux it's **ec2-user**, for ubuntu - **ubuntu**